# GFCI breaker trips, but GFCI outlet does not?

Tags: gfci

Little background before I ask question. I pulled a lines from main panel to outside subpanel, some 130 ft away. Put double pole regular breaker in the main panel (60A). In the sub panel I placed on 15A double pole GFCI breaker and one regular 15A sinle pole breaker. Single pole breaker line feeds to GFCI outlet. That outlet never trips, I can test it, I can reset it, I can put load on it, and no problem. I even tested it with outlet tester. No problems. Now if I turn on other double pole breaker, it trips immediately. If I leave that twisted wire from the breaker connected to the white bus, but disconnect white wire from my breaker, my breaker naturally does not trip. I measure voltage and it shows 282V between the poles on the breaker, and 141 between each of the poles and white bus. Then I thought, maybe the breaker is bad. So I took out double pole, and installed single pole GFCI breker, and same story with that one too. It immediately trips when I plug in white wire.

What else can I try and what could be the issue. I don't think that wire is damaged as pulling it was very smooth, and it is #6 AWG wire, and most of the wire is above ground.

Any ideas? How can I trouble shoot it further?

Comment: You're thinking backwards. The GFCI breaker in the second panel protects the branch circuit wiring connected to it, not the circuit feeding the panel. If it's tripping, there's a problem in the branch circuit.

Comment: Where are you located? Your voltage readings are high if you're in the US. You should be around 240 volts and 120 volts respectively.

Comment: Are the grounded (neutral) and grounding (earth) bars in the second panel isolated from each other? Is the second panel bonded to a grounding electrode?

Comment: @Tester101: Located in Dallas, TX

Comment: @Tester101: I understand that it protects circuit in sub panel . The thing is, as soon as I plug in the breaker, and turn on the power it trips, but only when I connect white wire to the bus where other white wires are connected to. If only coiled white wire is connected to the bus it does not trip. From main panel I run 4 wires, black, red, white and green. Green is grounding connected to the grounding bus, white to neutral and black and red to line 1 and line 2 ports.

Comment: Are you feeding only 240 volt loads from the double pole GFCI, or 120 volt and 240 volt loads? If you're feeding 120 volt loads, the circuit is not complete without the white grounded (neutral) wire connected.

Comment: 240V, but my reading on the double pole between red and black is 282V

Comment: I'm confused by your description of the wiring.  If you're only feeding 240 volt loads from the double pole GFCI breaker, there should be no white wire attached to the breaker (unless you're using a white as a repurposed ungrounded conductor).  The white coiled wire from the breaker should be connected to the grounded (neutral) bus, but there should be nothing connected to the grounded (neutral) terminal on the breaker.

Comment: I'm also concerned by your high voltage readings. You should verify that whatever device you're using to take measurements is functioning properly, and is correctly calibrated. If the measuring device is functioning properly, you should investigate why the voltage is so high.

Comment: @Tester101: Figured it out. My mistake. The breaker has 3 slots and pig tail white wire. I assumed that I needed to run one more white wire and connect it to the middle slot, just by the pig tail white wire. So, what I was doing was connecting, red, black, pig tail white, and then one more white.

Comment: Where were you connecting the other end of the additional white, to the neutral bar?

Comment: You should answer your own question. If somebody else comes along with the same problem, your answer could help them.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. My mistake. The breaker has 3 slots and pig tail white wire. I assumed that I needed to run one more white wire and connect it to the middle slot and neutral bus, not just by the pig tail white wire. It turned out that I needed to connect only pig tail white wire to neutral bus. Unfortunately I misplaced the package for the breaker and did not read instructions prior to installing it.